# mysql how do I detect missing values from the sequence?

Tags: mysql

im making a url shortener and im using the id for my hash

but theres a problem with auto incre mysql

```
URL tabel
id         short_hashbase62
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          4
6          6
7          7
8          8
12         c
```

the missing values are 5 and 9 10 11

question: **how could i select the 5 with mysql?** then the second select should be 9, and forth on.

there are some similar question but its to complex to understand;

[Detect missing values in a (auto-incremented) sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659725/detect-missing-values-in-a-auto-incremented-sequence)

[Aligning sequences with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220580/aligning-sequences-with-missing-values)

Comment: How do we know that 13 and 14 aren't 'missing'? And why does it matter that 5, 9, 10, and 11 are?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with @SergioTulentsev's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8659825/1229023)? Here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c510e/2) implementing his approach; it's quite easy to augment it to your needs, I think.

Comment: @Strawberry its still haven't been use not skipped

Comment: @raina77ow can we get only the 5 or the first number match? or should we just use php to do the job or any language

Comment: @AdamRamadhan You should just keep calm, carry on, and not worry about missing numbers!

Comment: @Strawberry its for a url shortener, and im trying to replicate how t.co is using every space available

Comment: That statement makes no sense to me, but good luck anyway.

Comment: @Strawberry becouse the id 10 will turn into a, im using base62 for the algorithm, lets say we missed 11,12,13 thats 3 short words already. thanks mate